# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget | Flutter | DropDown Button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I got an error **Incorrect use of parentdata widget** when trying to add a DropdownButton within a row Widget.

Here I've added two elements, Text Widget and DropdownButton within a Row Widget

```
Row(
                    children: <Widget>[

                      Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text(' Source  :')),

                      Expanded(
                          flex: 4,
                          child: FutureBuilder<SourceData>(
                              future: sourceData,
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                             
                          return sourceDropDownList(snapshot.data.sources);
                              
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                              })

                        )   // FutureBuilder
                    ],
                  ),   // Row
```

Here's the DropDownList Function returning a DropdownButton

```
  Widget sourceDropDownList(List<Sources> sources) {
    var sourceNameList = List<String>();

    for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
      sourceNameList.add(sources[i].name);
    }

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue;
        });
      },

      items: sourceNameList.map((value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Here is the screenshot of exact error message :

```
[Error Message][1]
[Actual Representation of widget][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9QsX.png

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALAOT.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your list type.

```
 items: sourceNameList.map((String value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: value,
                            child: new Text(
                              value.name,
                            )
                          );
                        }).toList(),
```